# How to add TTTableView inside TTViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20, ttlauncherview

**Hi i am actually struggling with a problem for the past two days.**

I have a launcher view that calls a TTViewController. Inside that TTViewController I have a segmented controller that manage 3 TTTable that I have added with addSubView.

```
TTLauncherView>TTViewController>TTTableView or TTTableViewController
```

**Problem : I can't manage to make it work.**

I first tried adding three external TTTableViewController but it messed up my navigation after the first didSelectItem, i was unable to go back to the launcher.

I then tried to add manualy three TTTableViews and implement `<TTTableViewDelegate>` but could not make it work.

**Do you have any example or indication for me ?**
Thanks in advance.

*Ps : i can provide sample code if needed.*

**UPDATE**
I declared it as Pushtomodalviewcontroller which of course messed up the navigation after the launcher. Removed it and works fine even with TTTableViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I declared it as Pushtomodalviewcontroller which of course messed up the navigation after the launcher loaded his TTviewController. Removed it and works fine even with TTTableViewController.

Answer (score 1):

well, you probably better off using a `TTViewController` with three standard `UITableView` objects.

I'm pretty sure the `TTTableViewController` controller wasn't designed to be stacked together with another controller.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you have any tips on how to implement the protocols from TTTableViewControllerDelegate ?